# Слить-слиять - паронимы? Спряжение, если возможно

Tags: лексика, словообразование, глаголы

Вечер добрый!
Существительное СЛИЯНИЕ - по действию от глагола сливаться (гнезда: лить-слить-сливать-сливаться; Словообразовательный словарь русского языка, А.Н.Тихонов,1990). Согласно Викисловарю, родственное слово-глагол "слиять", но у Тихонова и в "поисковике" такой глагол отсутствует. Хотелось бы определиться:
есть или нет глагол слиять;
если есть, то как спрягается;
можно ли "отнести"  слить-слиять к паронимам (в списке нет)?
С уважением
Р.М.,  Эстония

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...есть или нет глагол ***слиять?***

.

Глагол ***слиять*** (в значениях *"изготовить литьем", "соединить посредством литья", "вообще соединить, смешать в одно целое, растворить одно в другом"*)  в русском языке был.  Практически вышел из употребления, но у писателей и поэтов встречается и в наши дни (в основном — в форме ***слиянный***).

См. примеры:

> *И тогда же, в 1342 году, Новгородская летопись сообщает: "Повеле владыка Василий **слиять** колокол велик к святой Софии и приведе
>   мастера с Москвы человека добра именем Бориса".*
>
> [***"Наше наследие", 1991***](https://books.google.ru/books?id=Sh48AQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%22%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F&dq=%22%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%22%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiz5ZHY9f_RAhVGEiwKHVtwCLsQ6AEIGjAA)

.

> *Все для главы твоей **слиять** в одну короны*
>
> *И, кроткие прияв из милых уст законы,*
>
> *Орудьем быть твоих ко подданным щедрот*
>
> *И видеть, что тобой счастлив весь смертных род.*
>
> [Ю. А. Нелединский-Мелецкий. Темире (1782)]

.

> *И наконец вспомнила, и горный вечер в багровом полыхании заката пахнул на нее **слиянным** запахом полыни, мяты, мелиссы и базилика… и
>   еще одного, терпкого смолистого запаха, стоящего над полем и
>   обнимающего всадника с конем…*
>
> [Дина Рубина. На солнечной стороне улицы (1980-2006)]

.

Глагол этот в ряде словарей зафиксирован. См., к примеру, у Ефремовой:

> ***слия́ть***
>
> сов. перех. *устар.*
>
> то же, что *слить* II (от *сливать* 1., 2., 3., 4.)
>
> [**Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф. Ефремова. 2000.**](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/245988/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: Не могли бы вы ответить на остальную часть вопросов?

Comment: Взаимоисключающие ответы.  Больше склоняюсь к мнению "slava1947" , искренне благодарю за компетентность и великолепные примеры.   Если все-таки "слиять" существует, то, возможно,  изменяется по  "схеме"   "сиять"?    Слияю-слияешь-слияет-слияем-слияете-слияют   -  возможна ли такая, "отсебятченная" интерпретация?  Кто-нибудь,  поправьте меня.

Answer (score 3):

Глагола "слиять" не существует, существительное "слияние" относится к глаголам "слить" и "слиться".

**Слить ― сли/яни/е  и слиться ― сли/яни/е**

**СЛИЯНИЕ**, -1. к Слить (4 зн.) и Слиться (1-2 зн.). С. рек. С. сословий. С. романтизма и реализма. С. стилей. С. звуков. 2. Место, где сливаются два водных потока. Городок стоит у слияния двух рек.

**СЛИТЬ.** 4. Соединив вместе, образовать целое. С. классы, группы. С. два цеха. С. карточки. С. две статьи в одну. С. два понятия в одно. Слова и музыка органично слиты.

**СЛИТЬСЯ,** св. 1. только 3 л. Соединиться в один поток. Ручей слился с рекой. 2. Соединившись с кем-, чем-л., составить одно целое. Наши усилия слились воедино.

**Дополнение**

**Устаревший глагол** "слиять" равен глаголу "слить" **в значении "соединить"**, но **существительные от этих глаголов образуются разные:** слитие (многозначное слово) и слияние (значение соединения), также сохранилось в высоком стиле причастие "слиянный": С морем видны вкруг слиянны небеса. Ломоносов.

Существительное "слитие" в значении "соединение" используется редко, вот как это примерно выглядит: И какой же дивный гул возникает в храме, сколь многозначно это **слитие** глубоких тонов...[А. И. Солженицын. Крохотки 1996-1999 (1996-1999)].

В основном же мы используем  слово "слияние" в самых разнообразных сферах жизни, например: Любовь, любовь — гласит преданье — Союз души с душой родной — Их съединенье, сочетанье, И роковое их **слиянье,** И поединок роковой (Ф. Тютчев).

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Согласна с дополнением Сибиллы: не паронимы.
 **2.** Не согласна с тем,что устаревший. Пример:

*Stack Overflow на русском — сайт вопросов и ответов для программистов*
  *Обновление*

Алгоритмически - это, по сути, та же самая сортировка слиянием (где массив разделяем на две части, а потом сливаем в исходный), только без использования озу. Серия - это как бы размер массива. В сортировке слиянием мы делим массивы до мельчайших массивов - массивов с единственным элементом. А затем слияем их. А затем слияем слитые и т.д. Так моя серия = 1 изначально...

**3.** Нашла для себя и Aer:
 БЕЗБУКВ.РУ
МОРФОЛОГИЧЕСКИЙ РАЗБОР СЛОВА СЛИЯТЬ

Предлагаем вашему вниманию результаты морфологического разбора слова  **слиять.**

*Начальная форма:*  **СЛИЯТЬ**
 *Часть речи:* Инфинитив
 *Грамматика:* совершенный вид, непереходный, действительный залог
 *Формы:* слиять, слиял, слияла, слияло, слияли, слияю, слияем, слияешь, слияете, слияет, слияют, слияв, слиявши, слияемте, слияй, слияйте, слиявший, слиявшего, слиявшему, слиявшим, слиявшем, слиявшая, слиявшей, слиявшую, слиявшею, слиявшее, слиявшие, слиявших, слиявшими

Comment: А как различаются по значению   в п. 2  глаголы "сливаем" и "слияем"? Может быть, там проблемы с переводом? Глагол "слиять" является устаревшим  для общелитературного применения и имеет соответствующую пометку в толковом словаре. Возможно, он применяется в специальной литературе, но с каким значением? Можно ли найти это значение в специальных словарях по информатике?

Comment: По поводу п.2: не сильна в программировании,не знаю нюансов; дата отрывка 05.11.2014.  Еще: "Многофазное слияние.-AlgoList"-там много.  Еще:v bhxd f on Июл 25, 2012 ОТВЕТИТЬ
Известен способ слияния Windows mobile с iOS,
также (возможно) известна замена android на iOS
таким образом, слияем две операционки и заменяем ими android.  Еще:29.05.2013, 20:49     Сортировка Слиянием    Слияем первую половину 0 2 3 9?и после этого тоже самое делаем со второй половиной массива,а потом оба слияем?И поясните,что делает буфер...

Comment: Думаю, что разобраться в подобных текстах могут только программисты. Мы же можем сказать только одно: глагол "слиять" отмечен в словарях как устаревший. В то же время   слова с такой пометкой могут использоваться и в современных текстах, но в этом случае они имеют особый стилевой статус.

Comment: Голос «от программистов». К слову, `merge` (в смысле «произвести слияние») в русифицированной системе управления версиями переведено именно как «Слить». Форма «слиять» не встречалась мне ни разу в статьях или книгах, а примеры из интернета обычно не могут быть авторитетным источником. Тот же StackOverflow заполняется простыми людьми (программистами, не филологами) и никакой корректуры не проходит.