# Синтаксическая связь между СПП

Tags: синтаксис

Не могу понять, о каком правиле идет речь ниже.
(Д.Э. Розенталь, Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация, пар.30)

**Когда каштанка проснулась, было уже светло, и с улицы доносился шум, какой бывает только днем.**

Мне непонятно пояснение, которое дается ниже:

*придаточная часть относится только к первому простому предложению, а связь его со вторым слабее, на что указывает вид глагола, различный в этих предложениях.*

Как так может быть, что из-за вида глагола связь между главным и зависимым настолько слаба, что оно (зависимое) относится к следующей части и не является общим элементом  и, следовательно, это обуславливает постановку запятой перед "и".

Что за это правило? Дайте, пожалуйста, объяснение или ссылку, где я могу узнать:
*как различие в грамматике вида влияет на связь между главным и зависимым?*

Comment: @М_Г Извините, а в чем смысл Вашей правки? Вы только  изничтожили хорошее слово "здравствуйте", которое никому не мешало. Первый раз я обратилась с вопросом на Форум в феврале,  и в нем (в вопросе) были и "вечер добрый",  и "с уважением". https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429935/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE И модератор их оставил. Правила изменились?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова. Хорошее слово "здравствуйте" вносит ненужный информационный шум. Это следует из правил сайта: : "Вопрос — ответ. Ничего лишнего." (https://rus.stackexchange.com/tour); "Не используйте подписи, статусы и приветствия" (https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)

Comment: Дмитрий, я не очень поняла ваши рассуждения на тему грамматики. Могу только добавить, что означает это правило. Иногда между двумя предложениями при наличии союз И существует тесная смысловая связь, и тогда запятая не ставится. Эта связь может обозначаться различным образом (общее обстоятельство, дополнение, вводное слово, а также придаточное предложение), иногда вопрос о наличии общего элемента решает автор.  Обычно объединяются небольшие по объёму , нераспространенные предложения.

Comment: В приведенном предложении  можно было бы посчитать придаточное общим элементом, но этому препятствуют определенные факторы: разный вид глаголов "было"  и "доносился"   и распространенность второго предложения определительным придаточным. Здесь также очень важна семантика, не только грамматика. Каштанка сразу увидела, что на улице светло, а уже потом стала прислушиваться к шуму.

Comment: Sibylla, меня всегда радовало, как человек относится к делу - старается объяснить основной принцым. А некоторым просто напомнить. В конкрентом примере - я понимаю, что предложения различны из-за очередности смысла, за счет лескичесекого придаточных частей и преслаутого вида глагола.
Я у вас спрашивал, верно ли то, что я вычитыл в интернете, а именно: из-за грамм особенностей глаголы несов вида спрягаются только в настоящем, а глаголы сов - только в будущем, но эту грамм особеность мы не замечаем, потому что она для нас, как носителей языка является очевидной.

Answer (score 3):

Уважаемый Дмитрий, чтобы понять исключение из правила, надо сначала понять само правило: [§ 30. Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133).

1) Розенталь: *Перед союзами **и, да** (в значении **и**), **или, либо** запятая не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения **объединены каким-либо общим элементом**: **Вскоре после восхода набежала туча и брызнул короткий дождь**.*

Что это значит? В сложном предложении две предикативные основы, два глагола совершенного вида, обозначающие определенный момент времени. Оба  события (набежала туча и брызнул дождь) происходят **одновременно,** поэтому важно в устной речи и на письме **обозначить эту связь.** Соответственно, на письме мы не ставим запятую, а в устной речи не делаем паузу.

2) Розенталь: *Общей может быть **придаточная часть** сложноподчиненного предложения:

**Уже совсем рассвело и народ стал подниматься, когда я вернулся в свою комнату**.*

Здесь **момент времени обозначен придаточным предложением**: к этому моменту закончилось одно действие (рассвело) и началось другое действие (стал подниматься).

3) Розенталь: *Но:

**Когда Каштанка проснулась, было уже светло, и с улицы доносился шум, какой бывает только днём** (Ч.) — придаточная часть относится только к первому простому предложению, а связь его со вторым слабее, на что указывает различный вид глаголов-сказуемых этих предложений.*

Здесь придаточное обозначает **момент времени**, когда уже рассвело (было уже светло), а несовершенный вид глагола "доносился" определяет не момент времени, а **происходящее действие** (без определения границ), поэтому придаточное к нему не относится.

Кроме того, это предложение начинает **новую тему,** связанную с размышлением Каштанки о том, что время уже ближе к полудню (судя по шуму на улице). Всё это говорит об отсутствии тесной связи между предложениями, соединенными союзом И, поэтому между ними ставится запятая и делается пауза в устной речи.

4) **Правила русского письма не являются формальными** (кем-то и зачем-то выдуманными), **они основаны на грамматике.** А грамматика в данном случае — это обозначение времени действия с помощью вида глагола, наречий времени и т. д.

Также вспомним, что **назначение пунктуационных знако**в —  это прояснить содержание текста, что и делается в данном случае (мы обозначаем или не обозначаем более тесную связь
предложений, связанных союзом И).

Comment: Я знаю, что есть разновременное и одновременной **Оба события происходят одновременно, поэтому важно в устной речи и на письме обозначить эту связь.**
Как я понимаю, это как бы вы говорите, как происходит у нас в языке согласование глагов, которое даже не знающие грамматики знают, потому что тебя собеседник не поймет, или есть какая-то грамм норм на сей счет. Видимо вы забыли указать, что это связано из-за грамм особености вида глагола
в настоящем времени спрягается только несовершенный вид; в будушем спрягается только совершенный вид
Тогда это обьясняет, почему я не могу постоить предложение,

Comment: Sibylla, прокоментируйте написанное. Правильно ли я рассуждаю?